# Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication()

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, upgrade

**While I was trying update react-native version from 0.68.2 to 0.70.6 I'm giving this error.**

System:
OS: macOS 13.2.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 69.48 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/sh
Binaries:
Node: 18.16.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 9.5.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 2023.09.18.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
Android SDK:
API Levels: 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33
Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.1, 34.0.0
System Images: android-25 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973
Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.20 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
react-native: 0.70.6 => 0.70.6
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found

```js
"dependencies": {
"@alessiocancian/react-native-actionsheet": "^3.2.0",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.3",
"@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
"@react-native-community/rxjs": "^6.5.4-custom",
"@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.8.0",
"@react-navigation/core": "5.12.5",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "5.7.2",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "5.2.10",
"@react-navigation/native": "5.7.6",
"@react-navigation/routers": "5.4.12",
"@react-navigation/stack": "5.9.0",
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"dayjs": "^1.8.33",
"localized-strings": "^0.2.4",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"moment": "^2.27.0",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-jsx-parser": "^1.29.0",
"react-moment": "^0.9.7",
"react-native": "0.70.6",
"react-native-background-upload": "^6.5.1",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.300.0",
"react-native-controlled-mentions": "^2.2.5",
"react-native-date-picker": "^3.2.3",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-debounce-input": "^1.0.5",
"react-native-device-info": "^5.6.5",
"react-native-document-picker": "^3.5.2",
"react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^2.5.4",
"react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.8",
"react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.16",
"react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.19",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.39.0",
"react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
"react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-inset-shadow": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
"react-native-onesignal": "4.5.0",
"react-native-options-menu": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
"react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
"react-native-prompt-android": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
"react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-share-menu": "^5.0.3",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.5.0",
"react-native-switch": "^1.5.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
"react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
"rn-tooltip": "^3.0.0",
"rxjs": "^6.6.0",
"socket.io-client": "^4.2.0",
"underscore": "^1.10.2"
}
```

*Please help me how can i solve this problem? I've tried many solutions before asking here.*